# OpenXML in SQL Server with dd/MM/yyyy format gives conversion error

Tags: sql-server, openxml

I have a SQL Server stored procedure with a XML string as a parameter. The XML string has date tag with `dd/MM/yyyy` date format. While using the `OpenXML` it gives conversion error. Even if I have the sql user login has default language setup as `British English`. It works fine with `MM-dd-yyyy` date format.

This is my code

```
Declare    @XML Nvarchar(MAX)                  
Set @XML=   '<root><ContractNo>100213</ContractNo><ContractDate>25/6/2012</ContractDate></root>'

Declare @idoc int

-- Create an internal representaion of XML                          
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @XML                          

-- Get the data from XML into respective variables                          
SELECT   ContractNo                          
,ContractDate                             
FROM OPENXML(@idoc,'root',2)                          
WITH ( ContractNo nvarchar(30)                          
,ContractDate Datetime                         
)
```

**Error:**

> *Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

Answer (score 2):

For reference, since you are using SQL Server 2005+, you should start using the XML datatype and XQuery.

```
Declare @XML nvarchar(max);
Set @XML = '<root><ContractNo>100213</ContractNo>
            <ContractDate>25/6/2012</ContractDate></root>';
DECLARE @realXML xml;
set @realXML = @XML;

SELECT @realXML.value('(/root/ContractNo)[1]', 'varchar(max)') ContractNo,
       CONVERT(DATETIME,
               @realXML.value('(/root/ContractDate)[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
               103) ContractDate;
```

`CONVERT()` gives you flexibility in handling the dates, but if you had to, you can set the **`dateformat`** setting.  The British English language has a "dmy" setting that should work with your data. Check that something else isn't resetting the dateformat. Otherwise, set it explicitly before the batch. e.g. this works:

```
set dateformat dmy;

Declare @XML nvarchar(max);
Set @XML = '<root><ContractNo>100213</ContractNo>
            <ContractDate>25/6/2012</ContractDate></root>';
DECLARE @realXML xml;
set @realXML = @XML;

SELECT @realXML.value('(/root/ContractNo)[1]', 'varchar(max)') ContractNo,
       @realXML.value('(/root/ContractDate)[1]', 'datetime') ContractDate;
```

Comment: Hello Richard , Yes if i use varchar it will work. But why its failing only with dd/MM/yyyy format, it works fine with MM/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: Is the date tag reading using OpenXML is not considering the datetime format setting for the connected sql server user.

Comment: Richard, Why it works with MM/dd/yyyy format properly. If in my above code , i set date as 6/25/2012 it works.     Set @XML=   '<root><ContractNo>100213</ContractNo><ContractDate>6/25/2012</ContractDate></root>'

Answer (score 1):

You can get your date as `varchar` and use [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx?ppud=4) in the field list using style 103 `dd/mm/yyyy`.

```
SELECT   ContractNo                          
,CONVERT(datetime, ContractDate, 103) as ContractDate
FROM OPENXML(@idoc,'root',2)                          
WITH ( ContractNo nvarchar(30)                          
,ContractDate varchar(10)                         
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Declare    @XML Nvarchar(MAX)                  
        Set @XML=   '<root><ContractNo>100213</ContractNo><ContractDate>25/6/2012</ContractDate></root>'

        Declare @idoc int

        -- Create an internal representaion of XML                          
        EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @XML                          

        -- Get the data from XML into respective variables                          
        SELECT   ContractNo                          
        ,Convert(Datetime, ContractDate,103)                            
        FROM OPENXML(@idoc,'root',2)                          
        WITH ( ContractNo nvarchar(30)                          
        ,ContractDate nvarchar(10)                        
        )
```